# How do you say "I'm turning 18 this September."

Tags: english-to-german

How do you say "I'm turning 18 this September." and heroes always get remembered but you know legends never die in German?

Comment: Please use one thread per question next time.

Comment: I voted to close this question since it is a question for a translation which is not within the scope of this project.

Comment: I also vote for closing. - In order to make this an acceptable question, you should at least add the best translation into German you can come up with by your own.

Comment: he papansin kayong dalawa kj amputs

Answer (score 2):

"Diesen September werde ich 18" or you can say "Diesen September werde ich volljährig".